# Application of Luca's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let, $p$ be a polynomial in $1$-complex variable. Suppose all zeros of $p$ are in the upper half plane $H=\{z\in \mathbb C|\Im(z)>0\}. $ Then , which are corrct ?

1. $\Im\left\{\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\right\}>0$ for $z\in \mathbb R$.
2. $\Re \left\{i\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\right\}<0$ for $z\in \mathbb R$.
3. $\Im\left\{\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\right\}>0$ for $z\in \mathbb C$ with $\Im (z)<0$.
4. $\Im\left\{\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\right\}>0$ for $z\in \mathbb C$ with $\Im (z)>0$.

I know that , since all roots of $p(z)$ lie in the upper half plane so, all roots of $p'(z)$ lie in the same upper half plane , from Luca's theorem.

But from there how we can say about real part or imaginary part of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, we have $p(z)=a(z-z_1)\dots(z-z_n)$ where $a\neq 0$ and $n$ is the degree of $p$. (Clearly $p(z)$ cannot be identically zero.) By the chain rule, we have
$$
p'(z)=a\left(\prod_{i\neq 1}(z-z_i)+\dots+\prod_{i\neq n}(z-z_i)\right)
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\prod_{i\neq k}(z-z_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^n(z-z_i)}
=\frac{1}{z-z_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{z-z_n}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\overline{z}-\overline{z_i}}{|z-z_i|^2}
$$
This explains why 1, 2, and 3 are all true; can you see why? For 4, you can construct an easy counterexample using $p(z)=z-i$.

Comment: Yes...all are clear..But where the condition ' All zeros of $p$ are in the upper half plane $H=\{z\in \mathbb C|\Im(z)>0\}$. '   is used ?

Comment: This means that $\Im z_i>0$, so $\Im(\bar{z_i})<0$. Consider the sign of the imaginary part of each contribution to $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ (written above).

Comment: Sir, beautiful answer but it contains little typo. When you had written $p'(z)=a(∑ +... + ∑)$ But, it is not correct!! It must be $p'(z)=a(∏ +... +∏)$ and further, in $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ the  summation symbols which used inside must be product symbol.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi oops--thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Welcome sir, now it's correct... :-)