# Complex Polynomial with roots in uppar half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p$ be a complex one variable polynomial. Suppose all zeros of $p$ are in upper half plane. Then which of the following is/are true

1.$ Im\frac{p^{\prime}(z)}{p(z)} >0  ~for~  z\in \mathbb{R} $

2.$ Re~ i\frac{p^{\prime}(z)}{p(z)} <0  ~for~  z\in \mathbb{R} $
and

3.$ Im\frac{p^{\prime}(z)}{p(z)} >0  ~for~  z\in \mathbb{C},$ with $Im (z)<0.$

4.$ Im\frac{p^{\prime}(z)}{p(z)} >0  ~for~  z\in \mathbb{C},$ with $Im (z)>0.$

I tried the question by taking a particular example that satisfies the hypothesis of the given question. For example if you choose $f(z)=z-i$ then the function $f$ has only one zero that is $i$ and which is in upper half plane. Now if we do calculation then $1 , 2 $and $3 $
are satisfied. But i like to solve the question in general way. What the question is in itself. What is the geometry behind the question. Please solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(\ln p)'=\frac{p'}{p}$.

Comment: If Possible please solve it...

Comment: $(\ln p)'=(\ln\prod (z-z_k))'=\sum(\ln(z-z_k))'=\sum\frac{1}{z-z_k}$. Think what happens for a monomial $z-z_k$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application of Luca's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351009/application-of-lucas-theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$p(z)=a(z-z_i)\cdot\ldots\cdot(z-z_n)\implies\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{z-z_k}$$

and for all $\;1\le k\le n\;$ :

$$\frac1{z-z_k}=\frac{\overline z-\overline z_k}{|z-z_k|^2}=\frac{(x-x_k)-(y-y_k)i}{|z-z_k|^2}\;,\;\;z=z+iy\;,\;\;z_k=x_k+iy_k\implies$$

$$Re\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x-x_k}
{|z-z_k|^2}\;,\;\;Im\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\color{red}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{y-y_k}{|z-z_k|^2}$$

Observe that (3) is **always** true...end the argument now.

Comment: But What about 1 and 2

Comment: Well, I'd say you have to do some work of your own *too*, right? For example, (1) is clearly false and it's not hard to come up with some examples. Well, what about the rest?

Comment: 1 is true...it is not false

Comment: if im(z)<0 then im(z-zi)<0 which implies im{1/(z-zi)} is positive so is 3rd option right....i also solved 3rd like this

Comment: Nop, the mistake was mine! $$z\in\Bbb R\implies y=0\implies y-y_k=-y_k<0\;$$ , and the minus sign **before** the sum sign in Im gives (1) as true...nice!

Comment: and 1 imply second is true? am i right?

Comment: Yes, indeed...see, with some little hlep you're solving by yourself.