# Sign of real and imaginary parts of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ when p has all zeros in the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let p be a polynomial in 1 complex variable. Suppose all zeros of p are in the upper half plane. Then 
1. Im $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} >0$ for z$\in$ R
2. Re i$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} <0$ for z $\in$R
3.Im $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} >0$ for z$\in$ C with $Im$ z$<0$
4.Im $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} >0$ for z$\in$ C with $Im$ z$>0$

Comment: Did you try to work out some examples?

Comment: 4 is right. but I am not sure about the others.

Comment: This question has already an answer. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1363162)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application of Luca's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351009/application-of-lucas-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

For example,

$$\;f(z)=z-i\implies f'(z)=1\implies\frac{f'}f=\frac1{z-i}\cdot\frac{\overline z+i}{\overline z+i}=\frac{\overline z+i}{|z+i|^2}$$

Observe that

$$z\in\Bbb R\implies\text{Im}\left(\frac{f'}f\right)>0$$

$$i\frac{f'}f=\frac{-1+i\overline z}{|z+i|^2}\;,\;\;\text{so we get that}\;\;z\in\Bbb R\implies\text{Re}\left(i\frac{f'}f\right)<0$$

And this is only with one very simple example.